# Why do I need to run my makefile twice to compile my code

Tags: c++, c, makefile

So I am fairly new to building my own makefiles. I am having a weird issue where I need to run make twice in order for my executable to be generated. I have multiple files and they are in multiple sub folders. Each folder that contains files has there own makefile. In that make file I generate my object files and then push the object files to the main directory. Once all of my object files are generated I continue to try and create my executable.

This is my main makefile that runs the other makefiles.

```
# Declaration of variables
CC = g++
CFLAGS=-std=c++0x -Wall -lboost_system -lpthread
INCLUDE_PATH0=SocketIO/SocketServer/
INCLUDE_PATH1=SocketIO/SocketServer/SocketSession/


EXEC = run
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

TARGETS = SocketSess SocketServ maincpp

$(EXEC): $(TARGETS) $(wildcard *.o)
  $(CC) $(wildcard *.o) $(CFLAGS) -o $(EXEC)

maincpp: $(SOURCES)
  $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH0) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH1) -c $(SOURCES)
  ls
SocketSess:
  cd ./SocketIO/SocketServer/SocketSession ; make SocketSess

SocketServ:
  cd ./SocketIO/SocketServer ; make SocketServ

# To remove generated files
clean:
  rm -f $(EXEC) $(wildcard *.o)
  cd ./SocketIO/SocketServer/SocketSession ; make clean
  cd ./SocketIO/SocketServer ; make clean
```

This is one of my sub makefiles.

```
  # Declaration of variables
  CC = g++
  CFLAGS=-std=c++0x -Wall -lboost_system -lpthread
  INCLUDE_PATH=SocketSession/

  #Just build object file do not link yet
  SocketServ: SocketServer.cpp SocketServer.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) -c SocketServer.cpp
    mv *.o ../../

  clean:
    rm -f *.o*
```

This is the error I get.

```
    Main.cpp  Main.o  Makefile  SocketIO  SocketServer.o  SocketSession.o  test
    g++  -std=c++0x -Wall -lboost_system -lpthread -o run
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 1 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 2 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 3 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 4 has invalid symbol index 11
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 5 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 6 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 7 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 8 has invalid symbol index 12
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 9 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 10 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 11 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 12 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 13 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 14 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 15 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 16 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 17 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 18 has invalid symbol index 13
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 19 has invalid symbol index 21
    /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_line): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 2
    /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
    (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Comment: `$(wildcard *.o)`: There are no `.o` files the first time you run your makefile, so this will be empty. Perhaps you meant `$(OBJECTS)` instead, but there are all sorts of oddities with your Makefile that need fixing.

Comment: You want the makefile target of a rule to match the file name the rule creates.  For example, your SocketServ rule does not make that file.  It makes ../../SocketServer.o so that should be the rule target.

Comment: this line: $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(INCLUDE_PATH) -c SocketServer.cpp needs another parameter, perhaps: -o SocketServer.o

Comment: regarding your targets in the makefile(s), there is no actual file created with the targets names, so there needs to be a line: .PHONY $(TARGETS)  and 'clean' needs to be one of the phony targets.

Comment: the makefile is using 'mv' to move an object file to the main directory.  this removes the file from the current directory.  Then it will have to be generated all over again.  perhaps use ''cp' to copy the file.

Comment: this line: rm -f $(EXEC) $(wildcard *.o) should be rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)

Comment: this line: rm -f *.o* is very risky.  It should be rm -f *.o  although it would be better if $(OBJECTS) were defined in each of the sub directory makefiles the write it as: rm -f $(OBJECTS)

Comment: regarding this line: SocketSess:  there needs to be a blank/empty line before this target otherwise the above/prior target may exit with an error indication.

Comment: in the sub directory files, this kind of line: INCLUDE_PATH=SocketSession/ is not necessary nor is '-I$(INCLUDE_PATH)' needed in the compile statement  rather, use: '-I.'

Comment: this is a MUCH better way to write the compile statements: %.o: %.c $(DEPS) (line break)
 (tab)$(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)  where $(DEPS) is a list of any locally generated #include'd file names in the source file(s)

Comment: these items: -lboost_system -lpthread are not cflags, rather they are libraries, so probably should be referenced as: LIBS: -L<pathtolibs> -lboost_system -lpthread  however, the -L<pathtolibs> can be omitted if these libraries are in the standard library location(s)

Comment: this line: $(EXEC): $(TARGETS) $(wildcard *.o) is expecting to find the files listed in $(TARGETS) however, two of those files will NEVER exist and there is no .PHONY statement indicating that 2 of them are not going to produce a file with that target name.  This can/will confuse the make utility (although you may get lucky) suggest adding the appropriate .PHONY statement.

Comment: after looking at your makefile, I would suggest http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/howto_makefiles.html  (way to large to repeat here) which include a link to the make manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html which should be available far into the future

Comment: Okay I implemented most of these suggestions. It is clear I pretty much need to rewrite my makefile... I will continue doing this tomorrow and update everyone. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing that you have to describe subdirectory in makefile as make would not know you have sub directories.

```
SUBDIR = NameSubDirecory, NameSubDirecory
```

For other problems you have to read [Recursion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Recursion]) Make

Comment: I added this but it didn't seem to change much. I am able to locate sub directories without this.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this line of your error output:

```
g++  -std=c++0x -Wall -lboost_system -lpthread -o run
```

What files (either source files or object files) are being compiled to produce the output executable `run`?  Seeing as how there are no source files, I suspect that this is the source of the undefined reference to main.

Comment: Yeah for some reason it's not pulling the object files. The second time around it pulls the object files. I am just confused why it can't see them if they are the first thing generated anyway.